# Convert bash to matlab to define a file with string variable in pathway

Tags: bash, matlab

I need to use some toolbox in Matlab and haven't used Matlab in a long time. Wondering how to use a string variable for a placeholder when identifying a file in the pathway. For example in bash, ${SUBJID}/file1/abcd.nii, will the fullpath() in matlab works the same way, and how to save the output to the corresponding pathway?

```
a: A001/A001/file1/abcd.nii
b: A001/A001/file2/diff/mask.nii
output: A001/A001/file/output.txt    

bash:
export SUBJECTS_DIR=dir\
cd $SUBJECTS_DIR
SUBJID_LIST=[A001, A002, A003, B001, B002, ......]
for SUBJID in "${SUBJID_LIST[@]}"; do function 
-a ${SUBJID}/${SUBJID}/file1/abcd.nii 
-b ${SUBJID}/${SUBJID}/file2/diff/mask.nii 
-output ${SUBJID}/${SUBJID}/file/output; done

matlab:
SUBJID_LIST=[A001, A002, A003, B001, B002, ......]
for i in SUBJID_list
  path=dir\
  a=fullpath(path,i,abcd.nii) ??
  b=fullpath(path,i,mask.nii) ??
  output=function(a,b)
  writetable(output, "??? output.txt")
end
```

Comment: With a bit of browsing, looks like you want https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html

Comment: I am more concerned about using string variable to define the pathway not the matrix operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `fullfile` to concatenate file paths and `strrep` to replace your placeholder with a variable

Note that your paths and names should be enclosed in quotes in MATLAB.

Also `path` is a build-in function name, so I'd advise avoiding it as a variable name.

```matlab
SUBJID_LIST={'A001', 'A002', 'A003', 'B001', 'B002'};
myPath = 'dir\${SUBJID}\${SUBJID}\';
for i = 1:numel(SUBJID_LIST)
  iPath = strrep( myPath, '${SUBJID}', SUBJID_LIST{i} );
  a = fullfile(iPath, 'abcd.nii');
  b = fullfile(iPath, 'mask.nii');
  output = function(a,b);
  writetable(output, fullfile(iPath, 'output.txt');
end
```